# How can I check to see if a C# string array contains a value

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var a = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

How can I check this array to see if it contains "c"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one,

```
bool x = a.Contains("c");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Contains` extension method -  `a.Contains("c");`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the extension method of `System.Linq.Enumerable`, or if you fear that's performing too bad, the "old" way is the ugly

```
Array.IndexOf(a, "c") != -1
```

Another ugly possibility is to use one of the explicit interface implementations, like

```
((IList<string>)a).Contains("c")
```

In some ways, arrays have an obsolete feeling to them.